# Is there a statistical test for comparing my dataset percentages with published percentages?

Tags: dataset, statistics, hypothesis-testing, interpretation

I have a clinical dataset which is showing the percentage of A is 57% and B is 35% for where an tumours is initially found. However the literature is showing it is A is 73% and B is 23%.

Is there a statistical test I can use to see if my dataset is statistically similar to the literature? I only have the percentages of the literature, not their dataset or the number of participants in their study.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing   this also includes knowing the amount of data in each case.